# Meaning of "as + noun"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In three separate studies, researchers compared children who had slept
>   with night-lights in their rooms **as infants** to children who had not.

I can understand the sentence if there is no bold part. (*In three separate studies, researchers compared children who had slept with night-lights in their rooms to children who had not*). However, because of the bold part, I cannot understand the whole sentence. Could anyone explain what **as infants** in this sentence means?

Answer (score 3):

Although my primary language is not English but French, I understand that the meaning of "*as infants*" is "*when [they were] infants*", rather than "*as infants do*".

The context validates this interpretation: it would bring no objective information to state, in the context of a scientific study, that the children who did sleep with night-lights were doing "*as infants do*". That would also mean that we consider as a common truth that all infants invariably sleep with night-lights.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you extract the bold part and want to try to understand it apart from the context?

The sentence reads as follow:

- In three separate studies, researchers compared [children who had slept with night-lights in their rooms as infants] to [children who had not].

Researchers compared **one category of children** [*who had slept with night-lights in their rooms as infants*] to **another category of children** [*who had not*]

Let's look at the first category a bit closer:

- Children who had slept with night-lights in their rooms **as** infants -here "**as**" means "*in the role of*" and is similar to "**like**". The bold apart means "**as infants do**". ([**Cambridge grammar**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-or-like))

Comment: Isn't there any possibility that "as" is used as meaning of "from" in this context? So the full sentence means "children who used night lights since they were infants"?

Comment: @user198952 Definitely not. The children weren't infants. They were in the role of infants who sleep with the night-lights in their rooms.